# Add a column in dataframe conditionally from values in other dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
id   product_1 count
1        100     10
2        200     20
3        100     30
4        400     40
5        500     50
6        200     60
7        100     70
```

also  i have another table in dataframe df2

```
product    score
100         5
200         10
300         15
400         20
500         25
600         30
700         35
```

i have to create a new column `score` in my first df, taking values of score from df2 with  respect to product_1.

my final output should be. df =

```
id   product_1 count  score
1        100     10     5
2        200     20     10
3        100     30     5
4        400     40     20
5        500     50     25
6        200     60     10
7        100     70     5
```

Any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['score'] = df['product_1'].map(df2.set_index('product')['score'].to_dict())
print (df)
   id  product_1  count  score
0   1        100     10      5
1   2        200     20     10
2   3        100     30      5
3   4        400     40     20
4   5        500     50     25
5   6        200     60     10
6   7        100     70      5
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df,df2, left_on='product_1', right_on='product', how='left')
print (df)
   id  product_1  count  product  score
0   1        100     10      100      5
1   2        200     20      200     10
2   3        100     30      100      5
3   4        400     40      400     20
4   5        500     50      500     25
5   6        200     60      200     10
6   7        100     70      100      5
```

EDIT by comment:

```
df['score'] = df['product_1'].map(df2.set_index('product')['score'].to_dict())
df['final_score'] = (df['count'].mul(0.6).div(df.id)).add(df.score.mul(0.4))
print (df)
   id  product_1  count  score  final_score
0   1        100     10      5          8.0
1   2        200     20     10         10.0
2   3        100     30      5          8.0
3   4        400     40     20         14.0
4   5        500     50     25         16.0
5   6        200     60     10         10.0
6   7        100     70      5          8.0
```

Comment: working.  If handling large dataset, which one of the method
`map` or `merge` would take less time?

Comment: also if i want to create one more column 'final_score' i.e `(0.6*count/id + 0.4* score )` how do i do that

Comment: try `df['final_score'] = 0.6*df['count'].div(df.id).add(0.4.mul(df.score))`

Comment: my id and score are of type float and rest all are type object

Comment: what is expected first value fo verify?

Comment: id = 1 , count = 10, score = 5, it should be `(0.6*10/1 + 0.4*5)` = 8 but in ur final score it is 7.2

Comment: sorry, one parentheses was missing.

Comment: need `(df['count'].mul(0.6).div(df.id))`

Comment: Thank you for accepting! And for verifying solution.